# Treeview WPF Error 26 ItemTemplate and Item Template Selector are ignored for items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code to append items to a treeview, with MyTreeViewItem being a custom class that inherits from TreeViewItem:

```
        foreach (
            Site Site in
            SiteManager.SiteList.ToList()){

            MyTreeViewItem    HistoricalItem        = new MyTreeViewItem();

            HistoricalItem.LeftHeader.Content = Site.Profile.Username;
            HistoricalItem.BtmSubHeader3.Content = String.Format("Total: {0, 8:N0}", Site.Total);


            HistoricalItem.ItemsSource = Site.HistoricalList;
            HistoricalTree.Items.Add(HistoricalItem);

        }
```

and the following relevant XAML code::

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HistoricalTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label 
                Content="{Binding Path=Timestamp}"
                FontFamily="Consolas"
                Width="80" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Height="30"/>
            <Label 
                Content="{Binding Path=HeaderText}" 
                FontFamily="Consolas"
                Width="500" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Height="30"/>
            <Label 
                Content="{Binding Path=Total}" 
                FontFamily="Consolas"
                Width="250" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Height="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

                <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HistoricalTemplate}" 
                          Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                          Name="HistoricalTree" 
                          Background="{x:Null}" 
                          BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                          FontFamily="Consolas" 
                          FontSize="12">

                </TreeView>
```

Now the problem is that when I run this program, the template is not actually applied and I get Error 26: ItemTemplate is ignored. I am not sure why its being ignored or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: `ItemsSource` is set in XAML but you add a more item manually to `Items` collection? that could produce some unexpected result.

Comment: I didnt realize that was a mistake. Regardless, removing that line did not change the outcome.

Comment: delete all your code and start reading [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).